# case in my friendly URL

Tags: .htaccess

everyone..

I have problem in my URL. I rewrite my URL like this friendly url.

```
http://www.lankainstitute.com/1289/Mahesh Jayarathna HTTP/1./?1
```

But end of my url this string "HTTP/1./?1" has added..

can anybody tell me why is this???

this is from my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /profiles/tutors/index.php\?tutorCode=([0-9]+)&tutorName=([^&]+)&?([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^profiles/tutors/index\.php /%1/%2/?%3 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.+)/$ /profiles/tutors/index.php?tutorCode=$1&tutorName=$2 [L,QSA]
```

any comments are greatly appreciated..

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tweak your regular expression in the `%{THE_REQUEST}` match. When there isn't anything after the `tutorName=something` query string parameter, the space before the `HTTP/1.1` in the request never gets matched so it ends up as part of the `([^&]+)` grouping. Try tweaking the regex to look like this (and note in the rule, the backreference needs to be changed to `%4`):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /profiles/tutors/index.php\?tutorCode=([0-9]+)&tutorName=([^&\ ]+)(&([^\ ]+))?
RewriteRule ^profiles/tutors/index\.php /%1/%2/?%4 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank its work. But end of url '/' this slash added. How can I remove this from my URL. (After Tutor Name)

Comment: @user1543817 you kind of need that there because in the rule following that you are specifically matching a trailing slash: `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.+)/$`

Comment: @user1543817 If you remove the `/` after the tutor name, your next rule won't work because it wants that slash.

Comment: ok.. then tell me is there a way to do that??? if not, the user enter their url like this [code]http://www.lankainstitute.com/1289/Mahesh Jayarathna [code] then system can automaticall redirect to this url http://www.lankainstitute.com/1289/Mahesh Jayarathna/

Comment: Hello Jon Lin.. Can you tell me, is there a way to accomplish my task??? Thank You